# Call function at start of program before its defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program where a user inputs data, the data is turned into a list, and then the `main` function loops over the list until it has looped twice. Then the program should go back to `maininput`, so the user can input more data. However I can't get `maininput` to start before `main`, so `main` never gets the list to start the whole process. I tried calling maininput at the start of the program, obviously this can't work though since its not defined yet before line one.

Example structure:

```
def maininput():
    userdata = input('input data: ')
    list=[]
    #userdata turned into a list...

def main():
    counter = 0
    for input in list:
    counter +=1

    #stuff done with input

    if counter == 2:
        print('Program finished')
        maininput()
    else:
        pass 
while True:
        main()
```

Comment: It's fairly unclear what you're asking here.

Comment: `biglist1` is defined where? Can you show a [mcve] please?

Comment: Even if you call `maininput`, it's not clear what good that would do you. All it seems to do is modify some local variables that `main` won't have access to. If it returns something, `main` is ignoring the return value in the one place you call it.

Comment: Fixed the variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need some parameters in place to pass data around

```
def maininput():
   userdata = input('input data: ')
   #userdata turned into biglist1... 
   return biglist1

 # take a list and the amount of iterations performed 
def main(lst, counter=0):
    if counter == 2: # change recursion when counter is reached 
        print('Program finished')
        lst = maininput()
        return main(lst)  # also resetting the counter 
    for x in lst:
        #stuff done with input
    return main(lst, counter+1)  # endlessly recurse 

# No while loop needed, this function is recursive 
main(maininput())
```

Comment: I worded the question wrong, so props to figuring out that biglist1 was my list. I really just needed to make my list a global variable. So I feel kind of stupid now, but atleast the issue is resolved. Thanks for the help

Comment: Tip: Don't name a variable as `list` if you want to use `list()` built in function

Answer (score 1):

if the program have to run indefinitely, and if with big list you refer to the user input data, you can try this:

```
    def maininput():
    userdata = input('input data: ')
    #userdata turned into a list...
    return list

def main():
       counter = 0
       bigList = maininput()
       while True:
           for data in bigList:
               #doing stuff
            counter+=1
            if counter == 2:
                print('Program finished')
                main()
            else:
                pass

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just call `maininput()` before you hit the `while True` loop?

i.e:

```
maininput()
while True:
    main()
```

Comment: If i did that the main() loop would only run once before going back to maininput() no? I need it to run multiple times, then after a set amount of times go to maininput().

Comment: to be honest i don't really understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I was trying to parse the data from the first function into the second. The first function only needs to run once, because it makes a list with user input. Then the second function takes that list, and does stuff with each element. However it can only do it one at a time for time reasons, so it loops over each element once. At the end of the day I worded the question badly and didn't really understand what I was talking about, because the real problem was that I couldn't use a variable in the first function in the second, the fix obviously is to make the variable a global variable.